# Вывод списка пользователей, с которыми переписывался.

Tags: php, mysql

Мне кажется я немного перестарался..
Есть таблица с сообщениями:
[image]
Я хочу вытащить всех пользователей, с которыми я переписывался, и при этом узнать, есть ли новые сообщения от пользователя. У меня получился вот такой дикий запрос:

```
        $query=$dbh->prepare("
        SELECT DISTINCT sender_id, receiver_id, senders.username as sender_username, receivers.username as receiver_username, IFNULL(t2.new,0) as new
        FROM user_messages t1
        LEFT JOIN users senders ON senders.id=t1.sender_id
        LEFT JOIN users receivers ON receivers.id=t1.receiver_id
        LEFT JOIN
          (SELECT sender_id+receiver_id as gb, max(new) as new FROM user_messages WHERE receiver_id=? GROUP BY sender_id+receiver_id) t2
            ON t2.gb=t1.sender_id+t1.receiver_id
        WHERE t1.receiver_id=? OR t1.sender_id=?
        GROUP BY sender_id+receiver_id
        ORDER BY t1.id DESC
        ");
        $query->execute(array($my_uid,$my_uid,$my_uid));
```

Это вообще нормально, такие ужасы писать? Может есть какие-то способы оптимизировать хоть что-то? phpmyadmin на локальном хосте говорит, что справилась с этим запросом за 0.0049 сек, при том что на запросы по-проще уходит около 0,001сек.

Comment: IFNULL(t2.new,0) вот это со структурой как то не вяжется - поле new у вас определено как NOT Null)
А поподробнее - что в результате запроса нада получить? только список новых сообщений с атрибутами (от кого текст и т д) или дерево сообщений до них еще нада выводить?

Comment: @Ale_x  
t2.new - это максимум среди полей new для каждого собеседника. Если собеседник ещё не присылал сообщений, тогда как раз и получается null.  
В результате запроса надо получить список пользователей, которые присылали мне сообщения или которым я присылал сообщения, отсортированные по дате последнего сообщения + есть ли новые сообщения от моего собеседника.

Comment: 1. SELECT DISTINCT - то есть вы не уверены, что вам вернется ровно одна запись с уникальным набором полей и решили убрать дубли так? 
2. sender_id+receiver_id - это вообще непонятно что. т.е. 1+5 и 2+4 у вас имеют одинаковый смысл?
3. `t1.receiver_id=? OR t1.sender_id=?` - этим or'ом вы сразу и навсегда отказываетесь от любых индексов и если захотите ускорить данный запрос, то это выражение у вас будет в любом случае приводить к перебору.  

я так понимаю у вас сейчас в таблице 10 строк, когда число сообщений дойдет до 100к 0.0049 сек вам покажутся недостижимым значением.

Comment: А, да, ответ на вопрос: не нормально такие ужасы писать.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov
Да, DISTINCT я уже у себя убрал, толку от него нет.  
sender_id+receiver_id - так как у меня только либо sender, либо receiver  - всегда пользователь, то 1+5 и 2+4 никогда не будет. Будет 1+5 или 1+6 или 6+1: то есть sender_id+receiver_id=7 - все сообщения переписки с данным пользователем.  
И кстати я сейчас ещё поправил в вопросе запрос, там забыл GROUP BY в t2

Comment: @Yura Ivanov А воообще правда ужас получился.. может какую вспомогательную табличку сделать? или структуру например поменять?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, такой запрос будет выгоднее по производительности:

```
SELECT me.username as my_username, u.username as his_username, 
 msgs.direction, msgs.text, msgs.time, msgs.new
FROM
 (  SELECT id, sender_id as user_id, `text`, `time`, 1 as direction
      FROM user_messages
      WHERE receiver_id = $myid
  UNION ALL
    SELECT id, receiver_id, `text`, `time`, -1
      FROM user_messages
      WHERE sender_id = $myid) as msgs
JOIN users u on u.id = msgs.user_id
JOIN users me on me.id = $myid
```

Смысл в том, что при наличии индексов в `user_messages` по `receiver_id` и по `sender_id` они буду применятся для каждой части union в подзапросе, в случае `or` индексы применяться не будут.

Тамже в подзапросе можно регулировать количество записей, т.е. ограничивать по дате или по количеству (limit) и т.д.

ЗЫ Скобки можно раскрыть и сделать join  с каждой частью union'а, ну это на вкус и цвет...

Comment: @Yura Ivanov при большом количестве сообщений будет ли такой запрос быстро выполняться?  
Или мне стоит сделать как в предложенном мной ответе? (↑)  
Ваш запрос занял 0.0125 сек против моих 0.0022 сек.  
После добавления индекса для sender_id и receiver_id ваш запрос занял 0.0113 сек.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov и кстати в этом запросе вы выводите все сообщения, а мне это не надо, мне только надо узнать, есть ли непрочитанные.

Comment: @Dazar, ну вы же сами видите что запросы возвращают разное. зачем вы сравниваете время выполнения. мой запрос выводит больше данных. на большом объеме данных, ваш запрос просядет пропорционально количеству данных. чем больше их будет, тем дольше он будет выполняться, линейно.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, Но мне так много-то и не надо. я сделал GROUP By, убрал текст, добавил наличие новых сообщений.. вроде нормально.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from user_messages where receiver_id = {$id}
```

из  результата уже помечаем новые сообщения.

Возможно я Вас не так понял

Comment: я вывожу и тех, кто мне писал, и тех, кому я писал.
ваш код выводит только тех, кто мне писал

Comment: select * from user_messages where receiver_id = {$id} or  sender_id= {$id}

Comment: @naym ну да, у меня так и написано. только без фигурных скобочек. что они делают?

Answer (score 0):

Может быть сделать такую таблицу:

- пользователь
- собеседник
- время последнего сообщения
- есть ли новое(непрочитанное сообщение)

Тогда будем выводить собеседников, где пользователь=я, отсортированное по времени последнего сообщения.

Comment: тогда вам придется хранить удвоенное количество сообщений. для каждого пользователя будет полная история своей переписки (надеюсь хоть текста сообщения там не будет - в отдельной таблице, да?). у этого подхода есть свои преимущества (типа один пользователь может потереть свою историю, а у второго она останется), но минусов тоже хватает. это двойная запись vs не двойная в бухгалтерии.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov
Я же не собираюсь хранить все собщения.
я буду хранить только все связки между когда-то переписывавшимися людьми. да, в двойном количестве.

Comment: вы сами себе придумываете геморрой на ровном месте. сейчас вы придумали дополнительную сущность для выполнения одного класса запросов, придумаете еще один класс запросов, еще одну сущность создадите? потом вам придется в десять таблиц делать insert, это тупиковый путь, через полгода запутаетесь и не вспомните что и где надо контролировать.